# Can you specify context in signalr client events?

Tags: c#, backbone.js, requirejs, signalr

I'm attempting to use signalr for a board game app so that when a player moves a piece on one client, all clients can get updated. The problem I'm running into is not having a clear way to abstract the signalr parts of the app so that consumers of it don't need to worry about things like starting connections etc. I decided to skip sing the generated proxy and instead invoke things directly. The only remaining hurdle is that when the request is received by the client from the server, the this context in the event callback is of the hub, not of the owner of the callback. I'd like to know if there's a way to pass in a context.

Code:

Signalr service (like a base class to manage the connection and eventually events):

```
define('service.signalr', ['jquery'], function ($) {
var connection = $.hubConnection();

var start = function () {
    connection.start();
};

return {connection: connection, start: start}
});
```

Service with specific functionality - in this case handling piece movement:

```
define('service.game', ['jquery', 'service.signalr'], function ($, signalr) {

var gameHubProxy = signalr.connection.createHubProxy('gameHub');

var addHandler = function (name, callback) {
    gameHubProxy.on(name, callback);
}

var moveFigure = function (figureId, targetSpaceId) {
    var deferred = $.Deferred();
    gameHubProxy.invoke('moveFigure', figureId, targetSpaceId).done(function () { deferred.resolve(); });
    return deferred.promise();
};

return { moveFigure: moveFigure, addHandler: addHandler }
});
```

Calling the server method on the service (the event trigger is for the client performing the action so it doesn't process twice):

```
define('model.space', ['backbone', 'service.game'], function (Backbone, gameService) {
var Space = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: { id: 0, figure: null },
    moveFigure: function (figureId) {
        var self = this;
        var spaceId = self.get('id');
        gameService.moveFigure(figureId, spaceId).done(function () {
            self.trigger('figureMoved', figureId, spaceId, false);
        });
    }
});

return Space;
});
```

And trying to listen to the server's response:

```
define('view.board', ['jquery', 'underscore', 'backbone', 'helpers', 'bootstrapData', 'service.game', 'aggregate.space'], function ($, _, Backbone, helpers, bootstrapData, gameService, Space) {
var Board = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function () {
        this.spaces = new Space.Collection(bootstrapData.spaces);

        this.listenTo(this.spaces, 'figureMoved', this.updateFigurePosition);
        gameService.addHandler('figureMoved', this.updateFigurePosition);
    },
    updateFigurePosition: function (figureId, spaceId, drawFigure) {
        var figure = null;
        var oldSpace = this.spaces.find(function (space) {
            figure = space.get('figure');
            return figure && figure.id == figureId;
        });

        //code continues, but has already failed on this.spaces
    },
});

return Board;
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The obvious answer here after some sleep is to wire up the callback to a function in the module whose context I want that is just a passthrough to the actual method I want to call, so that this is then set appropriately. Such as:

```
initialize: function () {
        var self = this;
        self.spaces = new Space.Collection(bootstrapData.spaces);

        self.listenTo(self.spaces, 'figureMoved', self.updateFigurePosition);
        gameService.addHandler('figureMoved', function (figureId, spaceId, drawFigure) {
            self.updateFigurePosition(figureId, spaceId, drawFigure);
        });
    },
```

I still wonder if this can be a viable solution in all cases. Seems odd that I have to wrap my function in another function just so I can reference the variables I want. But I suspect this is less a problem with signalr, backbone, or require and more with a C# guy that's late to the Javascript party and still stumbles on some of the language's "features".